# setting the limit of number of cases in rows in R

Tags: r, export

I try to export tab delimited txt files from R. However, I would like to change the row after every 80th item.

For example,

```
a<-rep(1,200)
```

Now, there are 200 1s in a row. I export the vector with the code below.

```
write.table(t(a), "a.csv", ,sep="\t", col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

However, I would like to pass to next row after 80th item. In other words, I would like to set a limit for row which is 80.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps, you need `lst <- split(a, (seq_along(a)-1)%/%80 + 1);
 ; m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst)))); write.table(m1, "a.csv", sep="\t", col.names = FALSE, row.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks! It was sufficient answer :)

Answer (score 0):

We can split the 'a' into a `list` of vectors using a group created by `%/%`, `rbind` the `list` elements after padding the `length` to be equal in all the `list` elements and write it to file using `write.table`

```
lst <- split(a, (seq_along(a)-1)%/%80 + 1)
m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
write.table(m1, "a.csv", sep="\t", col.names = FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```